# Filter items in ng-for by search and show categories for those with results

Tags: angular, angular10

I have created an app to display elements from JSON.
I have 1500+ items in a big array, as well as in an array of arrays containing the items sorted by categories.

```js
const fullDataSet = [{name: 'Foo', category: 'vegetable'}, {name: 'Bar', category: 'fruit'}];

const = sortedByCategory = [
[{name: 'Foo', category: 'vegetable'}, {name: 'FooBis', category: 'vegetable'}],
[{name: 'Bar', category: 'fruit'}, {name: 'Baz', category: 'fruit'}]
];
```

I have implemented a filter to search by attributes in each item, that runs on my *ngFor.

The problem is that I need to have the items sorted by categories as well, with a title for each category.

I now have 2 loops, one for each category in the sortedByCategory array, and a nested one for each item in a category.

The problem is that if I the filtered results are empty, the category name is still there.

How could I structure my code so that the category names appear only when the nested ngFor loop has elements after the filter?
Is the idea of nested loops and filters necessary or could it be made in a more performant way?

Comment: You can see the problem in the app [here](https://material-icons-library.dugny.me/), if you search for a random string, all the category name are still there.
I've tried to pass a Subject to the filter, but it doesn't seem to work well and I was wondering if maybe I was just not in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Angular for a long time but here is my idea, the syntax might be messed :D

```
<div *ngFor="let item of categories">
     <Category *ngIf="item.length>0" data={{item}}/>
</div>
```

In your Category component:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
     <p>{{item.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue of getting the filtered items length :/